# Map strings with events

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

Is it possible to call a specific event based on a string?
Basically I want to do something like this:

1. Create a function with 2 parameters, a string and another function
   `Function(string,exec())`
2. Get the string and 'create' an event `onstring` (the string will
   always be a valid name, like click, mouseover etc.)
3. Apply this event (`onclick` for example) to a div of my choice.
4. Execute the 2 parameter when the div is clicked (the function `exec()`
   in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

You can use it like this:

```
var myEventType = 'click';
var myCallback = function() { console.log('I was called!'); };

var myDiv = document.getElementById('eventTarget');

myDiv.addEventListener(myEventType, myCallback);

/** click on div to fire myCallback */
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/isevicim/1/edit?html,javascript,console,output

Comment: What about the event OnMouseOver? EDIT: This is exactly what I was looking at. Where can I access all the events, so I know all the available valid events?

Comment: @nojtrid As seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events#Input_device_events, you can just use the string `'mouseover'` instead of `'click'`.